# Macro error in C99 and MS Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-c++, macros, c99

we have problems compiling our GCC C99 code with MSVS 2015. The problematic line seems to be a macro expansion, the problem occurs in this line:

```
const UA_QualifiedName dateName = UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(1, "current time");
```

The error is something like this

> IntelliSense a value of type âUA_Stringâ cannot be used to initialize an entity of type âUA_Int32â.

where macros are as follows:

```
#define UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(NS_INDEX, CHARS) (const UA_QualifiedName) { \
                        .namespaceIndex = NS_INDEX, .name = UA_STRING(CHARS) }
#define UA_STRING(CHARS) (UA_String) {strlen(CHARS), (UA_Byte*)CHARS }
```

and structs are

```
typedef struct {
    UA_Int32 length;
    UA_Byte *data;
} UA_String;
```

as well as

```
typedef struct {
    UA_UInt16 namespaceIndex;
    UA_String name;
} UA_QualifiedName;
```

It is valid C code as far as I can see it. Does anyone have an idea how we can workaround it for MSVS?

P.S.: apparently it seems to be the cast to `UA_String` in the second macro. However, removing it breaks the code for gcc and clang

Comment: These parentheses are not casts, but part of a compound literal for arrays and structures. The code also uses designated initialisers. Both features are C99. Very recent versions of Visual studio support these features, but most don't.

Comment: Is this a Compiler error or an IntelliSense error?

Comment: @MOehm removing designating initializers does not help

Comment: Hmm. VS 2015 seems recent enough to understand C99. As Werner Henze pointed out, it might be just Intellisense being tripped up by the "new-fangled" syntax. In this simple case, you could try rewriting the compound literals `(T) {a, b}` as function `T makeT(A a, B b) { T t = {a, b}; return t; }` and see whether that helps.

Comment: @MOehm I will try it, does VS 15 support inlined functions?

Comment: I'm not really an expert in Visual Sudio, but I guess so.

Answer (score 1):

C99 introduced support for a feature known as compound literals, which manifests as the *cast to `UA_String` in the second macro*. That isn't actually a cast. It's an initialisation, and use of an anonymous object. You're right, though... It's been valid C, for at least fifteen years now.

Unfortunately, as you have realised the hard way, MSVS doesn't fully support C99. That's right, there's perfectly valid, portable and compliant C code that was written *fifteen years ago* and *won't compile using MSVS*.

Microsoft *claims* support in the documentation (as they have introduced some C99ish functions). They haven't introduced any of the *core language* additions, such as *compound literals*, however. In fact, even parts of the library are broken in fundamental ways; `printf` and `scanf` need serious updates. MSVS hates C programmers :(

You might have some success compiling C99 code in MSVS by [Getting Started with the LLVM System using Microsoft Visual Studio](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html)...

Alternatively, *if you must* use Microsoft's compiler in spite of their lack of care about your code, the fix is simple enough... Just *don't use compound literals*.